# Vue Router beforeEnter vs beforeEach

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I am trying to redirect non-logged in user from all pages to `/login`. I tried `beforeEach()` but it doesn't fire when user enter site with direct url like `/home`, `/event`.

Per-Route Guard `beforeEnter()` works perfectly since it fires once the user lands on that particular page. However, it requires me to add `beforeEnter()` on every routes.

I am looking for a way to duplicate that `beforeEnter()` on almost every page on the router (even on dynamic pages) which non-logged in user will be redirected to `/login`.

This one works when user enter with direct url `/home`.

```
routes: [
  {
    path: '/home',
    name: 'home',
    beforeEnter(to, from, next){
      if ( to.name !== 'login' && !this.isloggedin ){
         next({
           path: 'login',
           replace: true
         })
      } else {
         next()
      }
    }
  },
  ...
]
```

This one only works after user entered the site and route changed

```
vm.$router.beforeEach((to, from, next)=>{
  if ( to.name !== 'login' && !this.isloggedin ){
    next({
      path: 'login',
      replace: true
    })
  } else {
    next();
  }
})
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It looks like this `beforeEach` is being defined inside an initialized component, which means the first routing has already occured.  Define it in the router module with your routes instead:

```js
const router = new VueRouter({
...
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next)=>{
  if ( to.name !== 'login' && !this.isloggedin ){
    next({
      path: 'login',
      replace: true
    })
  } else {
    next();
  }
})
```

Hopefully you are using Vuex and can import the store for `store.state.isloggedin`.  If not using Vuex yet, this illustrates why it is useful for global state.

Answer (score 1):

For a global and neat solution, you can control the router behavior in the `App.vue` using the `router.beforeResolve(async (to, from, next) => {});`.

**beforeResolve** is better than **beforeEach**, as **beforeResolve** will not load the component of the accessed path URL unless you fire manually the **next** function.

This is very helpful as you'll not render any interafce unless you check the authentication status of the user and then call `next()`.

Example:

```
   router.beforeResolve(async (to, from, next) => {
  // Check if the user is authenticated.
  let isUserAuthenticated = await apiRequestCustomFunction();

  // Redirect user to the login page if not authenticated.
  if (!isUserAuthenticated) {
    location.replace("https://example.com/signin");
    return false;
  }
  
  // When next() is called, the router will load the component corresponding
  // to the URL path.
  next();
});
```

**TIP: You can display a loader while you check if the user is authenticated or not and then take an action (redirect to sign in page or load the app normally).**

Comment: How would you display that loader you mention?

Comment: what are the use cases for beforeEach though? I was always using beforeEach and only now noticed that there is beforeResolve hook, so trying to understand the both better now.

Comment: This explanation is wrong.  Not only is `beforeResolve` not better than `beforeEach` (they are both useful), it comes after it, not before.  And both require `next`.